# How to collect heap dump (IBM JDK)

Tags: java, weblogic, heap-dump

```
$java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6460sr16fp26-20160508_01(SR16 FP26))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc64-64 jvmap6460sr16fp25-20160413_299433 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20160413_299433
JIT  - r9_20160328_114196
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR16_20160413_1159_B299433)
JCL  - 20160507_01
```

We are using IBM JDK and are facing high heap utilization issue for OSB Weblogic managed servers.

Kindly suggest how we can collect Heap dump for this JVM's using IBM JDK as we require to analyze the same and get rid of this memory/Heap issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argument to set

-Xdump:java+heap+system:events=user

By default in IBM JVM collects information when the application throws OOM either it could be native or heap.

For more information please refer this

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21242497#Help_Options

Answer (score 0):

IBM jvm by default generates logs when OOM accrue. However, we can specify what logs should be written by setting up below JVM argument.

```
-Xdump:java+system+heap+snap:events=throw+systhrow,filter=java/lang/OutOfMemoryError
```

This option helps to produce javacore, systemdump, heapdump and snaptrace when system throws out of memory error it could be a native or java.